# What trigger shifters would be compatible with my Nexus-8 internal gear hub?

Tags: shimano, compatibility, nexus

I've looked at similar questions to this and the only shifter that is brought up is the Shimano Alfine SL-S503 8-speed shifter. Are there any other compatible shifters (preferably trigger-shifters)?

Answer (score 2):

Shimano internal gear hubs require their own shifters. They are not compatible with derailleur shifters.

According to the [2017-18 line up chart](http://productinfo.shimano.com/download/?path=pdfs/archive/2017-2018_Line-up_chart_v024_en.pdf), the SL-S503 trigger or SL-C6000-8 'gripshifters' are your only choices.